Неправильно срабатывает условие
Есть мини игра, в котором нужно ловить объекты, съедобные и не съедобные. Съедобные добавляют очков, несъедобные отнимаются соответсвенно.
Когда функция спавнит объект, случайным образов присваивает к переменной объекта enemy значение true или false.
Далее условие проверяет эту переменную и в зависимости от значения, присваивает нужную картинку.
Но по какой-то причине, это условие отрабатывает неправильно.
Код на codepen.io
    window.onload = function () {
    Game()
}

function Game() {
    let c = document.querySelector("canvas");
    let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    c.width = innerWidth;
    c.height = innerHeight;
    c = c.getContext("2d");

    function startGame() {
        mouse = {
            x: innerWidth / 2,
            y: innerHeight - 33
        };

        touch = {
            x: innerWidth / 2,
            y: innerHeight - 33
        };
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
            mouse.x = event.clientX;
        });

        canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {
            let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            let root = document.documentElement;
            let touch = event.changedTouches[0];
            let touchX = parseInt(touch.clientX);
            event.preventDefault();
            mouse.x = touchX;
        });

        let player_width = 160;
        let player_height = 90;
        let playerImg = new Image();
        let score = 0;
        playerImg.src = "https://arteildev.github.io/game/img/player.svg";

        let _foods = [];
        let food_width = 64;
        let food_height = 64;

        function Player(x, y, width, height) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;

            this.draw = function () {
                c.beginPath();
                c.drawImage(playerImg, mouse.x - player_width, mouse.y - player_height);
                this.x = mouse.x - player_width
            };

            this.update = function () {
                this.draw();
            };
        }

        function Food(x, y, width, height, speed, enemy) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.speed = speed;
            this.enemy = enemy

            let foodImg = new Image();

            let foodimages = [
                "https://arteildev.github.io/game/img/food-1.png",
                "https://arteildev.github.io/game/img/food-2.png",
                "https://arteildev.github.io/game/img/food-3.png",
                "https://arteildev.github.io/game/img/food-4.png",
                "https://arteildev.github.io/game/img/food-5.png",
                "https://arteildev.github.io/game/img/food-6.png"
            ]

            let enemyImages = [
                "https://arteildev.github.io/game/img/enemy-1.png",
                "https://arteildev.github.io/game/img/enemy-2.png",
                "https://arteildev.github.io/game/img/enemy-3.png",
                "https://arteildev.github.io/game/img/enemy-4.png",
                "https://arteildev.github.io/game/img/enemy-5.png"
            ]

            if(!enemy) {
                foodImg.src = foodimages[Math.floor(Math.random() * foodimages.length)]
            } else {
                foodImg.src = enemyImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * enemyImages.length)]
            }

            this.draw = function () {
                c.beginPath();
                c.drawImage(foodImg, this.x, this.y);
            };

            this.update = function () {
                this.y += this.speed;
                this.draw();
            };
        }

        let __player = new Player(mouse.x, mouse.y, player_width, player_height);

        function drawFoods() {
            for (let _ = 0; _ < 1; _++) {
                let x = Math.random() * (innerWidth - food_width);
                let y = -food_height;
                let width = food_width;
                let height = food_height;
                let speed = Math.random() * 5;
                let enemy = Math.random() < .5;

                let __food = new Food(x, y, width, height, speed, enemy);
                _foods.push(__food);
            }
        } setInterval(drawFoods, 1000);

        function collision(a, b) {
            return a.x < b.x + b.width &&
                a.x + a.width > b.x &&
                a.y < b.y + b.height &&
                a.y + a.height > b.y-90;
        }

        c.font = "1em Arial";

        function stoperror() {
            return true;
        }
        window.onerror = stoperror;

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            c.beginPath();
            c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
            c.fillStyle = 'black';
            c.fillText("Score: " + score, innerWidth - 100, 20);

            __player.update();

            for (let k = 0; k < _foods.length; k++) {
                _foods[k].update();
            }

            for (let j = _foods.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (collision(_foods[j], __player)) {
                    _foods.splice(j, 1);
                    console.log(_foods[j]);
                    if(!_foods[j].enemy) {
                        score++;
                    } else {
                        score--;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        animate();
    } startGame();
}; 


Вы создаете массив объектов, а затем вы его мутируете _foods.splice(j, 1), позже обращаясь для проверки к индексу j, который уже j + 1, т.к. j был удален.
